# How to add extra spacing between paragraphs?

Tags: spacing

Here is some baseline code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
Hello
I am here

I am here?


How about here?

\end{document}
```

that gets:

```
Hello I am here
I am here?
How about here?
```

but I want there to be, for example, two lined of spacing between `I am here?` and `How about here?`. How can I accomplish this? Do I need `\\`?

Comment: If you want to add a bit of vertical space only in a few places, `\smallskip`, `\medskip` or `\bigskip` might do the trick. See [http://latexref.xyz/_005cbigskip-_0026-_005cmedskip-_0026-_005csmallskip.html](http://latexref.xyz/_005cbigskip-_0026-_005cmedskip-_0026-_005csmallskip.html)

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking to do. Thanks @gernot

Answer (score 4):

Your code already produces a blank line between paragraphs:

[image]

If you want to increase the space, use

```
\usepackage[skip=3cm]{parskip}
```

which produces

[image]

Choose whatever space you need.

Never use `\\`  to try to force space between paragraphs.